# set of all possible $n$-tuple combinations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am dealing with the really simple problem of generating a pin code programmatically. Like *"A1B"* And now I would like to write it down mathematically. To show how much unique variations of pin codes exists for a specific $n$.

What I have already:

---

A code contains of $n$ symbols from the set $\text{C}$

where

$n \in \mathbb{N}; n \ge 1$

$\text{A} = \{ ``A",``B",``C"\}$

$\text{B} = \{ ``1",``2",``3"\}$

$\text{C} = \text{A} \cup \text{B}$

The set $\text{D}_n$ of all possible combinations of a $n$-long code is described as

$\text{D}_n =$ **???**

So that
$\text{D}_3 = \{ ``AAA", ``AAB", ``AAC", ..., ``AA1", ``AA2", ..., ``333"\}$

So the number of all possible variations
$\vert \text{D}_n \vert = \vert \text{C} \vert ^n$

---

EDIT:
Better Question:

How can I write that the elements of $\text{C}$ come togehter as an Tuple (or whatever) and how to place $n$ in this form?

$\text{D}_n =$ **???**

Comment: Can you say $D_n=C^n$?

Comment: @Henry in the last line I wrote $\vert \text{D}_n \vert = \vert \text{C} \vert^n$ already

Comment: Should I construct the "code" as an n-tuple? eg triple ("A", "A", "1") ?

Comment: -> The set $\text{D}_n$ of all possible combinations of a $n$-tuple is described as

$\text{D}_n =$ **???**

Comment: Is this the right way:


$\text{D}_n = \{  (\underbrace{\text{C}_1, \text{C}_1,  \dots, \text{C}_1}_{\mathrm{n\times}} ), (\underbrace{\text{C}_1, \text{C}_1,  \dots, \text{C}_2}_{\mathrm{n\times}} ), \dots, (\underbrace{\text{C}_6, \text{C}_6,  \dots, \text{C}_6}_{\mathrm{n\times}} ) \}$

Comment: what you wrote was that the cardinality of $D_n$ was the $n$th power of the cardinality of $C$.  I am suggesting $D_n$ is $C^n$ as sets, or at least there is a natural isomorphism between them

Comment: @Henry the goal is to show how many unique combinations are there.
-> how much elements are in $\text{D}_n$  -> Whats the cardinality of  $\text{D}_n$ ?
Maybe I am doing something terrible wrong. I'm not a mathematician

Comment: You have already answered that.  $|C|=6$ so $|D_n|=6^n$

Comment: Ok. now I think I understand what I am doing wrong here. I ask the wrong question.
@Henry
I should ask:Is there a way to write $\text{D}_n =$ in a better form? How can I write that these elements of $\text{C}$ come togehter as an Tuple (or whatever) and how to place $n$ in this form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research I think this could be a solution.

Now I describe a code as a $n$-tupel, eg a triple ("A", "2", "B"):

$\text{D}_n = \{ \space (\text{x}_1, \dots, \text{x}_n ) \space | \space \text{x}_1, \dots, \text{x}_n \in \text{C} \space \}$